# Python - Copy element

Tags: python, selenium, element

I've been practicing Python watching tutorials and reading books and I'm struggling with the `copy` function. I'm trying to copy an `ID` that gets populated into an *element box*, so I locate the element and try to copy it but doesn't work. :(

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').copy2.copy()
```

I receive this error -

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'copy2'

[image]

I want to have my program copy the numbers in the 'Search ID' box.

Comment: Can you share the link or html? The image is of no use at all, it could be constructed a thousand different ways.

Comment: A `WebElement` instance has no `copy2` attribute in Python selenium bindings.

Comment: I can't share that exact link but here is an example: http://www.seleniumhq.org/ I'd like to copy the text inside the "edit this page" element

Comment: `find_element_by_css_selector("#editPage a").text`? Or using an xpath `.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='editPage']/a").text`

Comment: alexce's comment is correct. there is no such thing as "copy2". What follows the find_element_by_xpath command is a method that is called on the object that find_element_by_expath returns. When alecxe says there is no such copy2 attribute in the webelement bindings that is the answer. You are calling a method called "copy2" on the result of the previous call. You probably wanted to just call copy or nothing at all and just capture the element itself.

Comment: @phtnm28, you can share the html without sharing the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A WebElement instance has no copy2 attribute in Python selenium
>   bindings. – alecxe 1 hour ago

Thank you Alexcxe for this answer

The resolution:
Originally what I had wanted to do was copy the text in an element field and save it for later use. What I have done now to resolve the issue is save the text.

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]'): print ("This is the shopID") print (element.text)
```

Now I have it saved when I run the program

Comment: @alecxe is right, thing is that you can't use `find_element_by_xpath().copy2` and nobody understands what are you trying to copy and where, can you please explain

Comment: what is `copy2`, the only thing i have found where copy2 is used is `shutil.copy2` and you don't mention it anywhere, please provide more information